# Switching transistor for micro solenoid

Tags: transistors, clock, coil, solenoid

You may have seen some previous posts of mine asking various questions about frequency dividers. I have a circuit I think I am happy with for producing at 1Hz 12.5-25% duty cycle.

I now would like to use that to switch a solenoid on and off once per second for a wristwatch. I only have very rough numbers because I have not determined if I will be making the coil from scratch or using a purchased one but the numbers I expect are:

4V maximum, pulling around 1.5A peak and 350mA continuous.

Given these numbers, noting that the solenoid will fire for 250ms once every second, do you think the [R8002KND3](https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/discrete/transistor/mosfet/r8002knd3tl1-e.pdf) would be appropriate?

Additionally, I am using one [AP2138](https://www.digikey.com/en/datasheets/diodes-incorporated/diodes-incorporated-ap2138_9) linear voltage regulator to regulate a 3.7V lipo battery to the control circuit. Is it okay to run this solenoid-transistor circuit from the same regulator, or is it common practice to have a dedicated regulator to isolate high(er) power components like a solenoid from the low power logic of the same voltage?

Comment: 350 mA for 24 hours is over eight ampere hours.  The battery will be **enormous** for a wrist watch.  [This 8000mAh 3.7V cell](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/YDL2018032987/dp/B07BTV4J17) is twelve centimeters long, six centimeters wide, and 8 millimeters thick. That's half the length of my forearm and wider than my forearm at the wrist.

Comment: I am glad you pointed that out. This solenoid is actually a major gray are for his project. It is really difficult for me to guess at what solenoid specs are even necessary to actuate a watch mechanism.  The above specs are a worst-case scenario, so if I get a switching transistor that can handle that then I should be fine with anything less right?

Comment: Side note, your calculation did not consider that I am using a 1Hz 25% square wave. The calculation should look like:  (0.350 A)*(0.25)*(24 hr) = 2.1 Ah.  Even still, this is too much for the 500 Ah battery I plan to use for at least 3 days on the wrist. I think a smaller coil is definitely needed.

Comment: It should ideally take **very** little power to drive a mechanical wrist watch.  [The Bulova Accutron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulova#Accutron) was an electrically powered mechanical wrist watch.  It used a typical small watch battery and ran for months.  [Have a look at its insides.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:AccutronMech.jpg)

Comment: I ignored the duty cycle since you said "350mA continuous."  That would normally be the average power.

Comment: Ahh gotchya, I was more saying that when the solenoid is first switched on there will be a peak jump draw of up to 1.5A and by the end of the 0.25s pulse the draw will have levelled out to around 350mA.  I am obsessed with watches, and am painfully aware that the one I am constructing cannot compete. I am working on this project because I love watches and engineering and felt like making my own if I could to learn more about electronics. Most quartz watches have custom ICs that are microscopic and draw microamps. since I am making my own with off the shelf parts there will be shortcomings.

Comment: Take a look at the itty bitty little coils in the Bulova.  They won't take much current.  Yours is going to have to be that small and efficient to be of any use in a wrist watch.  The duty cycle is rather unintersting for your task.  You need a pulse to pull or push the movement once each second.  All you do is slam the solenoid to make it move.  You don't need (or want) the solenoid itself to stay on for very long.

Comment: Will do, do you have any recommendation regarding my question about what FET I should be using to fire the solenoid, and if I should use a separate regulator for just the coil or if I can use the same 3.3v source as the logic circuit?

Comment: The FET depends on the coil and operating voltage - as yet unspecified.

Comment: assuming the specs I listed, 3.3v, for a 2 ohms (max) coil.  assume the coil will run around 1.5 amp at most ever. Is there a good general use surface mount FET that can switch at 3.3v and handle 1.5 amps with low quiescent current?  while prototyping I am okay if the switch is a little overkill, I just need to start somewhere and make refinements later on.

Comment: 3.3volts / 2ohms = 1.65 amps

Comment: Sorry but surely you've got it spectacularly wrong with your solenoid current and it's far tinier. A watch doesn't have a mechanical load large enough to need that solenoid power. And the long history of watches doesn't use anything like that much power. So choosing a FET is putting the cart before the horse. And you've got other things to have concern about long before the FET.

Comment: I am sure you are absolutely correct, at this pint though, I would like to create a test circuit to verify my electronics. If I can build a small test board using an off the shelf micro solenoid then I can move on with making a more efficient one later. With that process in mind I need some kind of general use MOSFET to power the coil, but I am not sure what one would be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect the wristwatch stepper coil directly between two GPIO pins on a microcontroller, or between any two CMOS complementary outputs. They often need a bipolar drive and you'd need two outputs because of that.

Any sort of a solenoid, short of very high impedance
"TTL drive" types (last made in Eastern Germany AFAIK), will consume more power than the wristwatch stepper coil ever will. You can emulate the wristwatch stepper coil with a 1-10kOhm resistor probably.

Those coils are wound from absurdly thin wire with resistance in the ballpark of 10-100 Ohm/ft, and they are designed to operate from 1.0-1.5V.

Because your operating voltage will be >2.5x higher than needed by the coil, you should first measure resistance of the wristwatch coil, then add a series resistor of about 1.5x that value to the circuit, so that the coil is not overloaded.

Basically, for a 3.7V supply, you don't need any regulators. But you definitely want a tiny fast-acting 10-50mA fuse to protect the battery and wiring from short circuits. I'd suggest to use CMOS 4000-series logic to generate the clock from a 32kHz watch crystal and divide it down to a couple Hz, then feed that into the wristwatch stepper coil, perhaps through a couple of paralleled gates acting as buffers. For bipolar drive you'd need a Johnson counter with two pickup points. It'll work fine from a 3.7V lithium cell all the way down to fully discharged state (that you should avoid anyway - never run those cells to full discharge, leave at least 10% of charge).

Experiment first to determine the drive sequence that the wristwatch stepper you're using requires. Some work from simple pulses, some need bipolar alternating +/- drive, some need bipolar pulses separated by off-periods. When driving from "complementary" outputs, with both outputs high or low the coil is turned off, although it acts as an electrodynamic brake, so you may have to use tristate buffers to truly disconnect the coil during the off period as that may improve performance somewhat. The pin protection circuits in typical CMOS digital logic or MCU will do just fine to shunt the inductive kick from the coil.